# Bootstrap datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my datatable

```
<table id="example" class="table display" cellspacing="0">  
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Interest</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Visit</th>
            <th>Sales Person</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Interest</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Visit</th>
            <th>Sales Person</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * from enquiry where cmpId='$idCompany'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $time = $row['time'];
        $date = explode(" ", $time);
        $dateonly = $date[0];    
    ?>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $row['id']" data-target="#commentModal" data-toggle="modal" class="commentView"><?php echo $row['fname'] ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mobile'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['interest'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sex'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dateonly ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sales'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the first td has an a tag so can i can open a modal.

Javascript for modal opening

```
 <script>
     $(".commentView").click(function(e){                 
            e.preventDefault();
            
            var view_id = $(this).attr("href");
            console.log(view_id);
            datastring = 'memberId='+view_id;
        $.ajax({
            url: "targetComment.php",
            data: datastring,
            type:"POST",
            text:"json"
         }).done(function(info) {    
        //         console.log(info);
               $('#commentModal').html(info);
         });
         });
         $('#commentModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        //$('#memberInfo').modal('hide')
       location.reload();
    });  
</script>
```

My modal is completely fine and working properly......

the javascript of the data table

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
} );
```

} );

[image: AS u can see in the image the bottom scroll search is completely ruined because of the a tag.]

[image: Basically the javascript function is converting td into select option and the value of the option returning everything thats inside the td tag.]

AS u can see in the image the bottom scroll search is completely ruined because of the "a" tag.
Basically the javascript function is converting td into select option and the value of the option returning everything thats inside the td tag.
Note : I have linked/added all the js and css file for datatable
PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the text out of the stored html.

Get column index from outer loop and use that in inner loop to use to identify which column needs text from html

```
var cols = this.api().columns();

cols.every(function(colIdx) {

    var column = this;

    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                $(this).val()
            );

            column
                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                .draw();
        });
    var data = column.data().unique().sort()
    data.each(function(d, j) {
        if (colIdx == 0) {
            d = $(d).text()
        }
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
    });

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yL9sws65/)**</kbd>

Comment: its saying column.footer is not a function??

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle, plunker or other sandbox

Comment: hey check out this link i only want to put "a" tag in td so please try coz i am not able to put it in fiddlejs

Comment: why not? datatables is available on cdn

Comment: can u please help me??

Comment: working here...note how `external resources` used for scripts and css https://jsfiddle.net/yL9sws65/